# How to generate HTML report by specflow3.4.3?

Tags: html, cmd, report, specflow

How to generate HTML report by specflow 3.4.3? I can not find specflow.exe in the path after specflow update from 2.x.
I would like to use comment line after test executed to create HTML report.  (VS 2019 and C# and Nunit3)

Answer (score 0):

With SpecFlow 3 we removed the specflow.exe and all its features. Details can be found in this issue: https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/1036

The source is still available (https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow.Reports), but nobody has yet ported it to SpecFlow 3.

But there are alternatives to it.

We just released the SpecFlow+ LivingDoc Generator two weeks ago. The announcement is here: https://specflow.org/blog/introducing-the-specflow-plus-livingdoc-generator/

It is a SpecFlow Plugin and a CLI program to generate a standalone HTML file that has nice features like:

- Display test execution results of your Scenarios and Features
- Powerful searching and filtering
- Preview scenarios with test values
- Link scenarios to work items

Here is a screenshot of it:
[image]

There is also the reporting feature of the [SpecFlow+ Runner](https://specflow.org/plus/runner/). But for that, you have to switch unit test runner.

So I would recommend the SpecFlow+ LivingDoc Generator solution. It works with all the supported unit test frameworks of SpecFlow (xUnit, MSTest, NUnit, and SpecFlow+ Runner).

You only need to add a NuGet package to your project, let your scenarios run and run a cli program to generate the HTML- File

---

Full Disclosure: I am one of the develops of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response, and it works well for me to create HTML report.
One question is that I have run my test script by NUnit cmd. and create xml result file.
Is it possible that the json file converted from xml file?  or by any cmd line?

Comment: So that we can trigger the test in Teamcity accordingly.

Comment: The FeatureData.json is a completely new file. NUnit should still generate the xml file you need. SpecFlow is not doing anything with it. Perhaps you need some additional libraries to get again the NUnit xml file (something like https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit.Extension.NUnitV2ResultWriter/)